# How to parse this json structure in listview angular2 nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-services, angular2-nativescript

**json structure :**

```
{
  "Employee": [
       {"id":1,"name":"Dan" },
       {"id":2,"name":"Stack" },
       .....
    ]
}
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
 ngOnInit() {
 console.log("first", "Test");

    this.globalReader.getObjectData()
      .subscribe(data => this.getData = JSON.stringify(data),  ---> Response printed successfully here.I'm able to print it in label.
       error => alert(error),
       () => console.log("finished")

      );      

  }
```

**Edit:**

**component:**

```
  <label text ="{{getData }}" ></label>



  getObjectData() {

    return this._http.get('/page/emp.json')
      .map((response :Response) => response.json());

  }
```

After that I don't know how to parse the json and print it in listview for this structure. I referred some videos and grocery application. But I'm unable to get the result still.I'm very much confused with arrayname Employee.

I need to print only the `name` from response in listview.

Comment: Can you show us more of your component code (what type do you expect `this.getData` to be?) and maybe also your template? `JSON.stringify(data)` will just print your data as a json serialized string.

Comment: @FredrikLundin yes sure . I need to print only the name.please check my edited post

Comment: Thanks, can you also show the `globalReader.getObjectData()` function, so we can see what it's returning?

Comment: @FredrikLundin its returning this response perfectly.as I'm able to see that in console . `{
  "Employee": [

{"id":1,"name":"Dan" },
{"id":2,"name":"Stack" },
.....
]
}` I have added that part also .please check

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
<ListView [items]="employees" row="1">
    <template let-item="item">
        <Label [text]="item.name"></Label>
    </template>
</ListView>

// Create Employee Class:

export class Employee {
    constructor(public id: string, public name: string) {}
}

// Your component:

this.employees: Array<Employee> = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.globalReader.getObjectData()
        .subscribe(data => { 
                      this.employees = data.Employee.map(item => new Employee(item.id, item.name);
                  }); 
        });      
}

// The getObjectData method of *globalReader* service:

getObjectData() {
    return this._http.get('/page/emp.json')
        .map((response :Response) => response.json().data);
}
```

Depending on the object returned by the http call, the .data may not be required:

```
getObjectData() {
    return this._http.get('/page/emp.json')
        .map((response :Response) => response.json());
}
```

Comment: thanks for an answer.still same issue.I think it might me for each loop missed on that.

Comment: please check this screenshot.https://ibb.co/hdOJYQ . it has been showing [object object] in every item.I'm getting `cannot read property Employee undefined in cmd`

Comment: I was used `for` insted `map`. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to map the data instead of Strigify data

```
this.globalReader.getObjectData()
  .subscribe(data => this.getData = data.employee.map(e => e.name))
```

You can get it like following :

```
<ListView [items]="getData">
    <template let-item="item">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label [text]='"ID: " + item.id'></Label>
            <Label [text]='"Name: " + item.name'></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </template>
</ListView>
```