# How to get particular details based on category using angular 2

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

***I have given below is my json object how to get citydetails where city_id=50?***

```
{
"status": 0,
"message": "success",
"citydetails": [
  {
        "city_id": "50",
        "city_name": "Pune"

    },
    {
        "city_id": "53",
        "city_name": "Mumbai"

    },
    {
        "city_id": "50",
        "city_name": "Pune"
    },
    {
        "city_id": "52",
        "city_name": "Banglore"

    },
    {
        "city_id": "50",
        "city_name": "Pune"

    }
]
}
```

Comment: your JSON object is wrong

Comment: where is the complete array? what is that you are trying to filter?

Comment: @Aravind,@NuttLoose: I have corrected my json, now it is valid one.    I want to get city details where city_id=50. Kindly help me

Comment: what did you correct???

Comment: @Aravind the commas at the end of cities

Comment: @Aravind.  Yes, exactly as mentioned NuttLoose

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629179/how-to-parse-this-json-structure-in-listview-angular2-nativescript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let json = {
 "status":0,
 "message":"success",
 "citydetails":[
  {
     "city_id":"50",
     "city_name":"Pune"
  },
  {
     "city_id":"53",
     "city_name":"Mumbai"
  },
  {
     "city_id":"50",
     "city_name":"Pune"
  },
  {
     "city_id":"52",
     "city_name":"Banglore"

  },
  {
     "city_id":"50",
     "city_name":"Pune"
  }]
};
```

Assuming above in your JSON, below code will filter the city objects.

```
let filteredCities = json.citydetails.filter(data => {
  return data.city_id === "50";
});
```

filteredCities object will contain only the filtered city objects as an Array

Comment: @NuttLoose--Kindly where i will add the filter in my .ts page. currently the json object i am getting from constructor. how to add the fileter and where i will add. below is my code inside the constructor: city_id:any;
  cityType: any[] = [];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private appMsg: AppCommonService, public navParams: NavParams ) {
         this.city_id= navParams.get('id');
         this.cityType=   this.appMsg.retrieveCityDetails();
             
  }

Comment: I don't see any json object in your constructor, you can apply it by assigning the json you get to whatever variable. just adding variable.filter() would work.

Comment: @NuttLoose--Gud Morg,OK I will check it and i will tell you.    I am retrieving object array from commonservice:  this.cityType= this.appMsg.retrieveCityDetails();. I have id and object array. I want to filter and i need to get particular city details